# Preventing overlapping appointment times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a confusing little problem in SQL-Server 2005 and Classic ASP.  I have the following table in the database

```
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| ProgramID | SystemID | ClientID | ProgramName  | ProgramStart            | ProgramEnd              | ProgramHours |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 22        | 18       | 4        | After Gym    | 1900-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 2hrs 0mins   |
| 23        | 18       | 4        | Free Weights | 1900-01-01 12:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 14:00:00.000 | 2hrs 0mins   |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

This basically shows a program that is assigned to a system and a client for a specific time period.  What I want to do is prevent a user from entering a third program that overlaps the times already used (e.g. 10am to 11am).  The creation page features drop menus for hours, minutes and am/pm for the start hour and the 3 more drop menus for the end hour.  What I want to do is fire an ajax script that looks for overlapping entries when the drop menu selection changes. If it finds one it fires a js alert.

How would you detect this overlap in SQL?

Any ideas would be greatly received.

Many Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Your question is really about SQL and nothing to do with classic asp, can you re-tag and edit your question to remove the irrelevant parts?

Comment: I have changed the tags accordingly. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE 
(time_from <= $from and time_to >= $to) or // determine if the new appointment is fully in an exitent
(time_from <= $from and $from < time_to and time_to <= $to) or // determine if the new appointment starts in an existing and ends after
(time_from >= $from and time_to >= $to and $to > time_from) or // determine if the new appointment starts before an existing and ends in
(time_from > $from and time_to < $to) // determine if the new appointment starts before and ends after
```

if more any records are selected there is an overlapping

edit: i corrected the statement. it should now work.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Programs WHERE 
(ProgramStart <= '1900-01-01 17:00:00.000' and ProgramEnd >= '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000') or
(ProgramStart <= '1900-01-01 17:00:00.000' and ProgramEnd <= '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000') or
(ProgramStart >= '1900-01-01 17:00:00.000' and ProgramEnd >= '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000') or
(ProgramStart > '1900-01-01 17:00:00.000' and ProgramEnd < '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000')

I ran the script above on the server and it returned all records even though it should have returned 0. The 3 records in the db are for: 9am to 11am, 11am to 1pm, 1pm to 4pm I am still at a loss.. Please help

Comment: ah. got fogot one point. assure that time_from is always before time_to. If you would allow the reverse definition of the appointment the statement will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select to see if date entered falls in any ranges:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as tCount FROM TABLE WHERE programStart <= formDate AND programEnd  <= formDate
```

If it returns tCount as being >=1 then there is an overlap.

Also, your program length shouldn't really be stored in the database, as it is technically repeated data that will need updating everytime you change a program time, I would recommend the value of this can be extracted when needed (using SQL dateDiff() for example).

Comment: SELECT COUNT(1) as tCount FROM Programs WHERE ProgramStart <= '1900-01-01 17:00:00.000' AND ProgramEnd <= '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000'

I ran the t-sql script above on the server and it returned all three records even though it shouldn't have returned anything.

The 3 records in the database are for:

9am to 11am
11am to 1pm
1pm to 4pm

I am still at a loss.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the problem with the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Program_Count FROM Programs
WHERE ('1900-01-01 10:00:01.000' BETWEEN ProgramStart AND ProgramEnd)
OR ('1900-01-01 10:59:59.000' BETWEEN ProgramStart   AND ProgramEnd)
OR (ProgramStart BETWEEN '1900-01-01 10:00:01.000' AND '1900-01-01 10:59:59.000')
OR (ProgramEnd BETWEEN '1900-01-01 10:00:01.000' AND '1900-01-01 10:59:59.000')
AND SystemID = 18;"
```

Thank you for all your suggestion which when combined and researched brought me this solution.